# What is causing Provisionning Packages to fail to install?

Tags: windows, kiosk

I am trying to set-up a PC as a kiosk, using a Provisionning Package.

When I log into the target computer, with a Domain Administrator account, and install the ppkg, I get the following error message:

```
ProvXML category 'Policies' failed with '0x800706D9' at CSP node 'NULL'. Policies applied successfully.
```

I have tried to figure out the meaning of the error code, and the [Microsoft Error Lookup Tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-code-lookup-tool) gives me

```
There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper error in Windows 10
```

Which does not help me much more.

Edit: XML used

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<WindowsCustomizations>
    <PackageConfig xmlns="urn:schemas-Microsoft-com:Windows-ICD-Package-Config.v1.0">
        <ID>{1871019b-9eef-466b-9cce-408d82689c1a}</ID>
        <Name>PTI</Name>
        <Version>1.4</Version>
        <OwnerType>OEM</OwnerType>
        <Rank>0</Rank>
        <Notes />
    </PackageConfig>
    <Settings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:windows-provisioning">
        <Customizations>
            <Common>
                <Accounts>
                    <Users>
                        <User UserName="pti">
                            <Password>password</Password>
                            <UserGroup>Standard Users</UserGroup>
                        </User>
                    </Users>
                </Accounts>
                <OOBE>
                    <Desktop>
                        <HideOobe>True</HideOobe>
                    </Desktop>
                </OOBE>
                <Policies>
                    <ApplicationManagement>
                        <AllowAllTrustedApps>Yes</AllowAllTrustedApps>
                    </ApplicationManagement>
                </Policies>
                <ProvisioningCommands>
                    <PrimaryContext>
                        <Command>
                            <CommandConfig Name="InstallShellLauncher">
                                <CommandLine>dism /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:Client-EmbeddedShellLauncher /all</CommandLine>
                            </CommandConfig>
                            <CommandConfig Name="InstallCustomLogon">
                                <CommandLine>dism /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:Client-EmbeddedLogon /all /norestart</CommandLine>
                            </CommandConfig>
                            <CommandConfig Name="SetACScreenTimeoutToNever">
                                <CommandLine>powercfg /setacvalueindex SCHEME_CURRENT 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99 3c0bc021-c8a8-4e07-a973-6b14cbcb2b7e 0</CommandLine>
                            </CommandConfig>
                            <CommandConfig Name="SetACSleepTimeoutToNever">
                                <CommandLine>powercfg /setacvalueindex SCHEME_CURRENT 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 29f6c1db-86da-48c5-9fdb-f2b67b1f44da 0</CommandLine>
                            </CommandConfig>
                            <CommandConfig Name="SetDCScreenTimeoutToNever">
                                <CommandLine>powercfg /setdcvalueindex SCHEME_CURRENT 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99 3c0bc021-c8a8-4e07-a973-6b14cbcb2b7e 0</CommandLine>
                            </CommandConfig>
                            <CommandConfig Name="SetDCSleepTimeoutToNever">
                                <CommandLine>powercfg /setdcvalueindex SCHEME_CURRENT 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 29f6c1db-86da-48c5-9fdb-f2b67b1f44da 0</CommandLine>
                            </CommandConfig>
                        </Command>
                    </PrimaryContext>
                </ProvisioningCommands>
                <SMISettings>
                    <AutoLogon>
                        <Enable>ENABLE</Enable>
                        <Password>password</Password>
                        <UserName>pti</UserName>
                    </AutoLogon>
                    <BrandingNeutral>17</BrandingNeutral>
                    <HideAutologonUI>True</HideAutologonUI>
                    <NoLockScreen>True</NoLockScreen>
                    <ShellLauncher>
                        <Enable>ENABLE</Enable>
                        <UserSpecificSettings>
                            <LocalUserSpecificSettings>
                                <LocalUserShellSetting Username="pti">
                                    <UserCustomShell>c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe -k https://superuser.com</UserCustomShell>
                                </LocalUserShellSetting>
                            </LocalUserSpecificSettings>
                        </UserSpecificSettings>
                    </ShellLauncher>
                    <UIVerbosityLevel>Suppress</UIVerbosityLevel>
                </SMISettings>
                <TabletMode>
                    <SignInMode>Tablet mode</SignInMode>
                </TabletMode>
            </Common>
        </Customizations>
    </Settings>
</WindowsCustomizations>
```

What does this error mean, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Would you be able to provide the XML you have used?  Please edit the question instead of attempting to submit a comment that contains it.  I presume you are applying this package before a user has logged into the machine?

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, I edited the XML in. I am logging into the PC with my own account (domain administrator), to install the package.

Comment: Try Policy instead of Policies since it’s that XML node it does not like